# inserted posted details into database

Tags: php, mysql

When a user registers with my website they are then required to enter personal details. The entered details will be added to the personaldetails table in my datbase. I have the following code but it does not work, I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help? I am getting error:query was empty

```
    $myusername=$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword=$_SESSION['mypassword'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $totalwins = $_POST['totalwins'];
    $totalloses = $_POST['totalloses'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $queryreg = mysql_query("

                INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','','$myusername','$mypassword''$firstname','$surname','$totalwins','$totalloses','$email','$country','$info','$dob' )
        ");

if (!mysql_query($sql))
      {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      else  {
      echo "<br><br>Your details have been successfully updated. Go back to the                 personal details page to view your updated information.";
    }
```

Comment: we don't have magic sphere.. which is the error ?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi. (You are vulnerable to sql injection with your current code)

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: `if (!mysql_query($sql))` where is $sql set?

Comment: `"$host"`, `"$username"`, etc... are indicative of cargo cult programming.

Comment: Yo dawg! I heard you like SQL injection so we got [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) to join your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are exposed to SQL injection with your code. Please, prepare and escape your post data! This is really important to prevent SQLinjection attacks. Please read thouroughly about it.

Then, the error occurs because of this

```
if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else  {
  echo "<br><br>Your details have been successfully updated. Go back to the                 personal details page to view your updated information.";
}
```

You don't seem to have a variable named $sql, and, you are executing two query's!

Please do the following and post your feedback

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','','$myusername','$mypassword''$firstname','$surname','$totalwins','$totalloses','$email','$country','$info','$dob' )";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else  {
  echo "<br><br>Your details have been successfully updated. Go back to the                 personal details page to view your updated information.";
}
```

Comment: sql = mysql_query("
   
    INSERT INTO $tbl_name (field3, field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13) VALUES('','','$myusername','$mypassword','$firstname','$surname','$totalwins','$totalloses','$email','$country','$info','$dob' )
   ");

 if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: still the same error? sorry im not familiar with using these comments

Comment: As with feedback I mean the error or results the script produces.

this isn't as much help for me to help you. 

Nevertheless, if you're using an auto incremented primary key, you should pass a 'null' value, on the fields you don't want to store a value. 

And by the way, are your columns really named "field1, field2, etc..."??? This is a bad programming convention. You should name your table columns accordingly.

Anyway, please, post the script result

Comment: Glad to help!!! 

**PLEASE** don't forget to escape your data before insertion as well

Answer (score 2):

If you use a primary field with autoincrement you should specify the field name:

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (field1,field2,field3 ecc) VALUES( ... )");
```

Also your code is vulernable to injection, uso PDO

Answer (score 0):

Query was empty because you din't have any assign value to $sql in line

```
if (!mysql_query($sql))
```

To solve, you must assign it like :

```
  $sql = "update  $tbl_name set ...";
  if (!mysql_query($sql))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that scare me with your code...

Change to the following (you had a missing comma after `$mypassword` and `$sql` wasn't setup right).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name ( [list columns here besides autoincrement ] ) 
    VALUES 
    ('', '$myusername', '$mypassword', '$firstname', '$surname', 
    '$totalwins', '$totalloses', '$email', '$country', '$info', '$dob' )");

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
```

Comment: Whoever is voting these answers down needs to provide some explanation.  It's hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: this is now the error i recieve

Comment: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Make sure the number of entries match. `INSERT INTO table ([number of columns must match number of values]) VALUES ([number of values must match number of columns])` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: do i start with field 1 or leave it out as it is autoincrement? e.g. INSERT INTO table (field1, field2.....) or (field2, field 3.....)

Comment: Leave the auto increment field out

Comment: @kevin628 All voted down for [encouraging bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756679/inserted-posted-details-into-database#comment13980361_10756679).